# Infomações não vem completas no Google Charts

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-charts

Boa tarde Guys,

Estou com dois problemas para esse mesmo código...

Um é quando eu apenas lanço o dia pra poder pegar as horas, ele me retornar o erro `Cannot read property 'getTime' of null` sendo que chega o valor...

O segundo é que eu escolho o intervalo do mês, de 01 a 31 do mês e ele duplica certas datas e não mostra o mês todo, como na imagem abaixo:

Código JS:

```
 google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart()
        {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
             data.addColumn('date');
             data.addColumn('timeofday');


            for(i = 0; i < e.length; i++){

                let totais = {};


             e[i].item.forEach(i => {

                if(! totais[i.date])
                {
                    totais[i.date] = moment.duration(0);
                }
                totais[i.date].add(moment.duration(i.hrWork));
            });



                Object.keys(totais).forEach(j =>{
                let duracao = totais[j];
                var hrWork = duracao.hours().toString().padStart(2, '0')+':'+duracao.minutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
                var hrwork = hrWork.split(':')
                console.log(hrwork)
                let date = e[i].date.split('-')
                data.addRow([new Date(date[2],date[1]-1,date[0]), [ parseInt(hrwork[0]), parseInt(hrwork[1])] ]);
            });
            } 


            var options = {
                chartArea: {

                     height:'60%'
                 },
                 bar: {

                   groupWidth: 30
                 },
                   height: 400,
                 explorer: {
                         maxZoomOut:4,
                         keepInBounds: true
                     },
                 hAxis: {
                   format: "MMM dd,YY",
                   slantedText: true,
                   slantedTextAngle: 45
                 },
                 vAxis: {
                   minValue:0,
                   format: 'h:mm a',
                 }
               };
          var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

          var chart_area = document.getElementById('chart');
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_area);
          chart.draw(view);

          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function(){
            document.getElementById('input').value = '<img src="'+chart.getImageURI()+'" class="img-fluid">';

          });

        chart.draw(data,options);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso alguem possa me dar um norte, fico grato!

Comment: Olá, é provável que você esteja recebendo a data no formato ISO 8601 corretamente porém seu script está tratando ela como string, neste caso você deve convertê-la para Date primeiro para ela fornecer acesso à subrotina getTime(). Só para reforçar: eu passo pela mesma situação em uma API em Go e procedo desta forma para resolver.

Comment: Valeu mano!! Só que não entendo o seguinte, quando seto o valor do mês toda, o gráfico plota normal, porém quando defino qualquer outro intervalo, ele dar este erro.

Comment: O valor da minha hora, vem como hora apenas ex:"05:20" daí dou split para separa e transformo em Inteiro para por no valor do addRow

Comment: Percebi tambem que ele só plota meu gráfico caso no intervalo selecionado tenha duas datas com valores, ex: 01-sep-2019 à 10-sep-2019, caso nesse intervalo só haja uma data com valor da hora trabalhada ele não plota.

Comment: Diêgo, não tenho experiência com Google Charts, vou passar esta. Um outro alguém deve manifestar ai com ajuda e conhecimento suficiente.